# Error in read_html.response(x$response, ..., base_url = x$url) : Forbidden (HTTP 403)

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

Using a package off GitHub (HoopR), I am trying to login in to a website so that I can scrape, but for some reason I am getting a Forbidden (HTTP 403) error. The login function is part of the HoopR package. My code was previously working well so I'm unsure what went wrong... This is a new error to me.

```
login(user_email = Sys.getenv("KP_USER"), user_pw = Sys.getenv("KP_PW")) #Uses HoopR package to log into Kenpom
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in read_html.response(x$response, ..., base_url = x$url) : 
Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

I have tried to correct this error by setting my user-agent with the following code, but still have no luck

```
require(httr)

headers = c(
  `user-agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
)

res <- httr::GET(url = 'https://kenpom.com/index.php', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers))
```

I hope this isn't a dumb question, but I was wondering if anybody could provide help or some other steps I can take to get over this hump. I've been working with this package all semester for an undergraduate class, so I'm a bit desperate to get over this hurdle. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting blocked by the firewall. Add Sys.sleep(sample(1:6, 1)) to your code to bypass it.

Answer (score -2):

SOLVED****

I honestly don't know exactly what fixed it, but I reinstalled R and Rstudio, Updated my macOS, and updated my login info to the website I was trying to scrape from. This issue is probably too niche for anybody else to gain value from, but I thought I would keep this here just in case.

Comment: This is better framed as a comment Not an answer.

Comment: I don't the issue is too niche, installation errors are pretty common with Mac systems so it would have been helpful to detail/document your solution.